# MySQLi - Better way to query select from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I can't seen to figure out how to query from multiple tables, using a "linking" table to point to it.
I have a table for "Shows" and a table for "Genres", I have a "linking table" in which I have `show_id` and `genre_id`. Which connects to the `id` in genres and `id` in shows. My issue is that I don't know if it is possible to collect the `name` from Genres table in the same select where I query the show.

Right now, this is what I'm doing:

```
$query = $DB->query('SELECT * FROM shows');

while ($show = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $get_genres = $DB->query('SELECT genre_id, show_id FROM shows_genres WHERE show_id = ' . $show['id']);
    $allgenres = '';
    while ($genre = $get_genres->fetch_assoc()) {
        $genre_name = $DB->query('SELECT id, name FROM genres WHERE id = ' . $genre['genre_id'])->fetch_assoc();
        $allgenres .= $genre_name['name'];
    }
```

And it is possible that on the "linking table" a show have more then one genre on it, multiple genre_id rows pointing to the same show_id.

Messy, isn't it? Is there how to select all this from the first query?

The tables structure is as follows:

```
SHOWS: id, title, summary
SHOWS_GENRES: show_id, genre_id
GENRES: id, name, description
```

Comment: you need to learn about `joins` :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a single SQL statement using JOINs:

```
SELECT
    g.name,
    g.description,
    s.title,
    s.summary
FROM SHOWS s
JOIN SHOWA_GENRES sg
ON s.id = sg.show_id
JOIN GENRES g
ON sg.genre_id = g.id
WHERE s.id = show['id']
ORDER BY g.name.s.title;
```

This will return one row per genre, with a comma separated list of show in that genre:

```
SELECT
    g.name,
    g.description,
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.title) as shows
FROM SHOWS s
JOIN SHOWA_GENRES sg
ON s.id = sg.show_id
JOIN GENRES g
ON sg.genre_id
GROUP BY g.id
ORDER BY g.name;
```

If you want a list of shows and their genres, you could use this:

```
SELECT
    s.title,
    s.summary,
    GROUP_CONCAT(g.name) as `genres`
FROM SHOWS s
JOIN SHOWA_GENRES sg
ON s.id = sg.show_id
JOIN GENRES g
ON sg.genre_id
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY s.title;
```

Comment: @Jeff: Not PHP code, just the SQL with a placeholder for the variable.

Comment: small typo: `SHOWA_GENRES` (lower case also?)

Comment: and the 2nd join `ON sg.genre_id` doesn't look complete (...sorry, it's not ment as criticizing, but as helping to be precise)

Comment: actually I did know that this id is a placeholder. maybe I understand this joins wrong, because, let's say I used id 700 for this, show 700 has 4 genres, when I while it. It's showing every single genre on database (repeating this show title in each row and repeating the same genre 4 times)

Comment: if you used this statement, it' because there something missing: `ON sg.genre_id=g.id`

Comment: well you're right. I didn't even notice it. But, another thing that I don't get on joins... How should I avoid it to repeat 4 times (according to number of genres)? And to print it as one and it's 4 genres?

Comment: read about the differences of a left join and a right join. I didn't specifically study your db structure....

Comment: In your code to display it, you detect if the show is repeated and display only the first time each is found. Used to be called a break-sort. Ot you can use GROUP_CONCAT on the genre columns and get a comma separated list of each of the genres for each show. You would also use a group by on the show's id column.